# Unity 2D. Find the coordinates of an object moving along the axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player which is rotating around one point and I need to make an enemy aim in front of the player to actually shoot and hit the player.

In the figure below, the red point is my object that is moving around yellow point (enemy), and im trying to find out how I can make the enemy shoot ahead to actually hit the red. If I shoot at the last known location, the bullet passes behind red. I want to calculate a position in front of red to aim at so that I can actually hit red.

Thanks [image]

Comment: Are you asking how to randomly generate directions pointing behind or in front of an object? Are you asking how to predict the future position of the object? The post is unclear about what you're actually interested in having answered, and the only question in it is a yes or no question (yes you can have advice).

Comment: Simplest solution might be: `direction = player.position + player.forward * certainDistanceInFrontOfPlayer - enemy.position);` where the certain distance would be calculated dependent on the distance from enemy to player, the bullet speed and the player speed

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to calculate how much angle does the red object sweep per second. `float A = 2 * Mathf.pi * Mathf.Rad2Deg * radius / red_linear_speed`

Multiply that with how long it takes for yellow's bullet to reach the circle. That's the amount of angle that you have to aim ahead of red. `FrontA = A * radius / bullet_speed`

Rotate the vector from yellow to red by that angle and shoot. (assuming y is up) `Vector3 shootDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis(FrontA, Vector3.up) * (red.transform.position - yellow.transform.position).normalized`

You may have to try -FrontA or Vector3.down at this last step to ensure you get the direction right.

You'll hit red, guaranteed!

Comment: Doesnt work actually. Bulets just keep being shooted into last known red position but not ahead.

Comment: In theory it should work. There may be a degree/radian angle mistake somewhere. Or there can be a Time.deltaTime issue somewhere. You should debug to see what's going on step by step. You can use Debug.DrawRay to see where shootDirection is pointing to.

Comment: Yeah i've tried debuging, and I got that 'frontA' is calculated properly, but then we just getting red.position multiplyed by bullet speed. I mean it seems like AngleAxis is redundant and doesn't affect on shooting vector, it just gives (0,0,0,1). And now i'm trying to get what went wrong there

Comment: I don't know how it works, but `Quaternion.Euler(0,0,(FrontA * A))` actually gives the result

Comment: Then your up vector must be Z. You can change Vector3.up with Vector3.front in my last code.